# NAT IP mapping using a request parameter

Tags: networking, firewall, router, nat

I want to do this.

I have a office firewall and all request from my system(`10.140.22.11`) will be routed through a NAT ip (`200.142.24.224`)

My system acts as a server. Any request made via internet should reach my system. How can I achieve this without going for a one to one static ip (i.e., with this common NAT ip of my firewall).

Is this possible ? Something like `http;//200.142.24.224:7001/myApp?destIP=10.140.22.11` will help ? Will the firewall able to route it `10.140.22.11` using the request parameter (destIP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your NAT to forward external traffic for `200.142.24.224` to the `10.140.22.11` IP address on your LAN.

Then, if you use `http//200.142.24.224:7001`, the requests will be sent to 10.140.22.11. No need for `myApp?destIP=10.140.22.11`.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Just one question. If all the requests are routed to 10.140.22.11, then if some other LAN machine (say 10.140.22.12) makes a request to external site (sat google.com), will 10.140.22.12 receive the response back or will that response too go back to 10.140.22.11

Comment: If you forward traffic with IP address 200.142.24.224, then other traffic from google.com will be forwarded to 10.140.22.12 (and not 10.140.22.11), because it will have a different ip address (not 200.142.24.224).

Comment: No. In my case, 10.140.22.12 also will be mapped to the same NAT (200.142.24.224)

Comment: I meant the google will have a different IP and PORT mapping organized by the NAT.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Kindly ignore my ignorance. I am very new to all these networking. I agree it will have a different port. On IP, All request from my LAN will be through 200.142.24.224. Isn't this a problem?

Comment: No, because you NAT performs translations with the IP address AND a port, which allows your 200.142.24.224 to be demultiplied 64K times, since the port value can take (nearly) any value between 0 and 65536. One IP address is used in 64K different ways. Although all outgoing communications will have 200.142.24.224 as the address, they will have a different port number.